# Australia PR 190 - relocate to a different state after applying EOI

Tags: visa, australia, pr

I recently got a competent English score in PTE which gives me 70 points without state sponsorship. So I am planning to apply for VISA 190 (with state sponsorship it will be 75)

But the problem is my project is ending on 31 August 2021 and my current visa(482) expires on 17 August 2021. It's uncertain whether or not my project will get extended or I will find another project in a different/same state or my company will send me back to my country without extending the visa.

With these uncertainties, if I apply for EOI for 190 visa in July (application will be open on July 1st usually, isn't it?), and after applying if I have to relocate to a different state or have to leave the country, what would happen?

Will my EOI be rejected because I am not present in the chosen state? When will I get the bridging visa? Immediately after applying for EOI?

If my company decided to extend my visa, that process will start in May since it has to be started 3 months before my 482 visa expires. Having applied for 482 visa extension will affect my EOI? If I haven't gotten the visa extension by July, can I still apply for EOI?

I hope you understand my situation, any suggestions for this scenario is very much appreciated. I am perplexed about what to do now.

Comment: Just in case, anyone had the same question, this thread might help them. https://www.expatforum.com/threads/moving-state-after-applying-for-eoi-190-state-sponsership.1514456/

Comment: Your title and the used tags are in contradiction.

Comment: "PR 160" is an Australian form, which comports with the OP's citing the score on the English proficiency test. I amended the title.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I am **not** a visa agent and I am most especially not **your** visa agent.

Posting just to point you to the official sources:

**Will my EOI be rejected because I am not present in the chosen state?**

Can't find anything that addresses this directly. Try reading https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/skilled-nominated-190#Eligibility where it says

> All state and territory government agencies have their own criteria for deciding who they will nominate. Contact the state or territory agency directly to find out more about their nomination process and what they want from you.

**When will I get the bridging visa? Immediately after applying for EOI?**

https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/moving-between-visas says

> An EOI is not a visa application and you will not be granted a Bridging visa by submitting an EOI. Your eligibility for a Bridging visa would only be considered once a valid visa application is lodged.

> If you are in Australia and the visa you hold is about to expire before you are invited and able to apply for a skilled visa, you will need to apply for another visa to remain in Australia.

> If you do not meet the requirements for the grant of another visa, you will need to depart Australia before your visa expires.

Obviously you'll have to do your own research or hire a qualified professional to see how your personal circumstances affect things.